# Google Places API mass download?

Tags: android, google-places-api

I'm developing an app where I need to display nearby places.
I'm currently using the Google Places API but it's kinda slow. I was wondering if I can store the places data for a city using the Places API.

If not, are there any other means I can get nearby place data and store them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Terms of Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms), no.

> **10.1.3 Restrictions against Copying or Data Export.**
>
> **(b) No Pre-Fetching, Caching, or Storage of Content.** You must not
>   pre-fetch, cache, or store any Content, except that you may store: (i)
>   limited amounts of Content for the purpose of improving the
>   performance of your Maps API Implementation if you do so temporarily
>   (and in no event for more than 30 calendar days), securely, and in a
>   manner that does not permit use of the Content outside of the Service;
>   and (ii) any content identifier or key that the Maps APIs
>   Documentation specifically permits you to store. For example, you must
>   not use the Content to create an independent database of "places" or
>   other local listings information.
>
> **(c) No Mass Downloads or Bulk Feeds of Content.** You must not use the
>   Service in a manner that gives you or any other person access to mass
>   downloads or bulk feeds of any Content, including but not limited to
>   numerical latitude or longitude coordinates, imagery, visible map
>   data, or places data (including business listings). For example, you
>   are not permitted to offer a batch geocoding service that uses Content
>   contained in the Maps API(s).