# storing full address from google places api

Tags: autocomplete, google-places-api, google-places

Users will be able to submit places through my site, providing title, description, address and other info. Info will be later used in mobile app and elsewhere.

Anyway, I was thinking to use autocomplete, powered by google places api. Am I allowed to store the full addres user types in, or selects from autocomplete list?
It is user provided information, the api is used to suggest and display on map, which is on the right from the form. The only thing I need is the full address.

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Probably.  Google's Terms of Service are a little vague in this respect, but what they appear to be prohibiting is bulk copying of their database.  In your case you're using Places to assist the user.  Of course it's impossible to say how Google will choose to change or interpret their TOS in the future, but you should be on safe ground.

Also see: [Google Places API mass download?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27846330/google-places-api-mass-download/27848613#27848613)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. And how about storing the address parts from the callback?

Comment: I believe so. I think Google's being deliberately vague, but as long as you're using Google to assist with a search, you're on solid ground.  The key here is that each row in your own database is generated by your user, not by a bulk download from Google.

Comment: thanks, you cleared a lot for me.  I prevously read that there are problems storing such info. Do you think the lat/lng data also can be taken from the callback and stored without restrictions?

Comment: Use your discretion, be smart and cautious, and always be prepared that Google may change their TOS at any time.  Remember there are other location services out there and build your application with enough flexibility that if it turns out you can't do what you need to do with Google you can make a change that is seamless and invisible to your users.